# Transaction exception while pushing transaction

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosjs, eosio-code, keosd

While calling the push transaction API with the following body

```
    {
      "signatures": ["SIG_K1_K5umBpyieHE6czvtDMEAVjypG5Zz5sYo4NKbUkqJfe562mX22aLGwwZsYSQJLhBZi5s3hvjg6zVfS3ZucM97Ji5KNXSm4a"],
      "compression": "none",
      "packed_context_free_data": "",
      "packed_trx": "0076e95b042960a4d7b9000000000100000020476d964a000000000000806b010000000000ea305500000000a8ed3232080000000000ea305500"
    }
```

Getting the Below error, Kindly help :

```
 {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal Service Error",
        "error": {
            "code": 3040000,
            "name": "transaction_exception",
            "what": "Transaction exception",
            "details": []
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the raw, unpacked transaction look like?  It sounds like there is an error trying to invoke your transaction.  Also try checking the `nodeos` log and see if anything outputs there.